# ceph stuck in active+remapped+backfill_toofull after lvextend an OSD's volume

Tags: ceph

I have a 2 OSDs ceph cluster. The initial size of backing volumes was 16GB. Then I shutdown OSDs, did a `lvextend` on both, and turn OSDs on again.
Now `ceph osd df` shows:

[image: ceph osd df]

But `ceph -s` show it's stucked at `active+remapped+backfill_toofull` for 50 pgs:
[image: ceph -s]

I tried to understand the mechanism by reading CRUSH algorithm but seems a lot of effort and knowledge is required.
It would be very appreciated if anyone could describe the behaviour (why stuck in toofull despite the free space is increased significantly.) and help me to resolve this state.

Comment: do you have data (ceph osd) for before "did a lvextend on both" & "free space is increased significantly."?

Comment: and I might say 90% use is high.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes, the cluster had data and data is still available to clients.

Comment: nope, you write "Now ceph osd df shows:" I meant output of `ceph osd df` as in your question before "did a lvextend on both"

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Comment: why have you done `lvextend`? what metrics pointed you to that? 
+ maybe you recall some numbers, like %USE before

Comment: The usage was about 11GB of 32GB. I wanted to increase the size of the cluster so I did `lvextend`, apparently the wrong way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131964/discussion-between-ahmad-ahmadi-and-martian2020).

Answer (score 0):

Your `RAW USE` is times larger than `DATA`.
Note: solution not tried, still this is what I've found.

[Re: Raw use 10 times higher than data use](https://www.spinics.net/lists/ceph-users/msg55668.html)

> Probably the first thing to check is if you have objects that are
> under the min_alloc size.  Those objects will result in wasted space
> as they will use the full min_alloc size.

Similar advice:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68185503/ceph-df-octopus-shows-used-is-7-times-higher-than-stored-in-erasure-coded-pool/68186461#68186461

> This is related to bluestore_min_alloc_size_hdd=64K (default on
> Octopus).
>
> If using Erasure Coding, data is broken up into smaller chunks, which
> each take 64K on disk.

Another way to fix the problem one may try to follow instructions on your second screen:

> add storage if this doesn't resolve itself